# How to pass parameters from PythonOperator to HttpSensor via XComs in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I want to send an HTTP request whose parameters depend on the result of a dependent Python callable. I am trying to use XComs for this purpose. Simplified example:

```
def get_index():
  return 0

get_index = PythonOperator(
  task_id='get_index',
  python_callable=get_index,
  dag=dag)

http_request = HttpSensor(
  task_id='send_http_request',
  http_conn_id=HTTP_HOST,
  endpoint=ENDPOINT,
  params={
    "index": "{{ ti.xcom_pull('get_index')  }}"
  },
  dag=dag)

get_index >> http_request
```

Unfortunately, after examining the options of the HTTP request I see the macro is not evaluated properly and instead of `0`, `{{ ti.xcom_pull('get_index')  }}` is sent. What might have gone wrong? Should I use the `HttpOperator` instead of `HttpSensor`?

Answer (score 1):

As [faeder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7036929/faeder) mentioned, jinja templates in `params` are currently not evaluated. I resolved the issue by switching to `SimpleHttpOperatr`s and putting the template in the `data` field.

Answer (score 0):

I think that params are deprecated and not scanned by the jinja templating engine in airflow. Try to use request_params instead of params (it's a a dictionary of string key/value pairs).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17141050)

Comment: @SirRufo Actually it does answer the question. In the Sensor described, it uses the jinja expression "{{ ti.xcom_pull('get_index')  }}" which is never read by airflow as a jinja template and therefore not repalaced by the values from xcom. If however, params is renamed as request_params, airflow interpret it and replaced "{{ ti.xcom_pull('get_index')  }}" by the value from XCom. Tested on my machine.

Comment: An answer with *I think* and *try* is more a suggestion that would fit perfect as a comment but not as a qualified answer.